# phonegap download and save images from a url to the application installation folder

Tags: android, ios, cordova, file-transfer

I am developing an application in phonegap that is supposed to work in both ios and android.
For this application i need to download all images from the server.I was able to download the images to the external memory card using the following code.

```
function storeIntelligrapeLogo() {
alert('start of file download');
var url = "http://www.kannuronlineservices.com/images/logo.png"; // image url
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
    alert('inside request file sysytem')
    var imagePath = 'file:///storage/sdcard0'+fs.root.fullPath + "/logo.png"; // full file path
    alert('inside request file sysytem path fs.root==' + fs.root);
    alert('inside request file sysytem path fs.root.fullPath==' + fs.root.fullPath);
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(url, imagePath, function(entry) {
        alert(entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Some error" + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}) }
```

Now i would like this to work in ios also.For that what is the file path i have to use
for 'file:///storage/sdcard0'.Then now the file is downloaded to the external memory card in android and i would like it to be downloaded to the application installation folder and so that when the application is uninstalled,the images also get deleted.Or please suggest me if there exist some other way of doing this,ie:downloading images from server folder and storing it locally with phonegap so that the application is expected to work in offline mode also.
Thanks.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something or does it not work if you just change the imagePath variable to one of the URLs specfied here? [cordova filesystem api](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md). For iOS that would be the documents - directory.

Comment: Hi Joonas Ahola,Thank you verymuch.I would like to have a sample code that works fine for both android and ios.The idea is,i will give a url to the methode and the function should save the image at the url to any of the folder that should be readable and writable so that up on uninstallation of the application should clear the data.

Comment: If your sample code works fine for android, it should work fine for iOS too, if you change the imagePath-variable to a proper folder. On iOS you should try `var imagePath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory+"/logo.png"`and on android `var imagePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory+"/logo.png"`

Comment: Hi,When i copied it and tested for android,The code is note executing below that line i had replaced.I think it is not identifying this ..cordova.file.dataDirectory

Comment: Hey, those URLs are available from version 1.2.0 of the file-plugin, update yours if it's older.

Comment: Hi Jonas Ahola,I am using phonegap build to build the app and my config.xml file contain the following.                                    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.0.1" />
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.2" />                                                           When i added its version as 1.2.0,Phonegap build shows me error that invalidplugin version..

Comment: hmm, it does indeed seem like that last version available for phonegap build is 1.0.1. That's weird since the last version in the plugin-repo seems to be 1.3.0. Try to change the code to `var imagePath = fs.rootFS.fullPath+"/Documents/logo.png"` on iOS and `var imagePath = fs.rootFS.fullPath+"/files/logo.png"` on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a phonegap plugin.

Look at http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/de.fastr.phonegap.plugins.downloader

It downloads multiple files to persistant storage on android and ios.